# how to make a list selected in my dropdownlist yii?

Tags: yii, dropdown

I get a list of email address from my query and i want the list to be selected by default in my form.How to achieve that? My code is

```
<div class="row col2">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email_to'); ?>
    <?php 

    foreach ($mailList as $eachValue){
         $selectedOptions[$eachValue] = array('selected' => 'selected');

    }

 echo $form->dropDownList($model,'email_to',$mailList,array('class'=>'span4 chosen','maxlength'=>20,'multiple' => 'multiple','options'=>$selectedOptions,'readonly'=>true));

?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'email_to'); ?>
</div>
```

My $mailList contains only email address.

Comment: Can you show the html generated for this select ?

Comment: this is code from my html  form.I get the list of email and i have to make them all selected.

Comment: no, I am asking about the generated html of the select, it must be something like `<option value=1>something@something.com</option>`

Comment: <select id="Reply_email_to" class="span4 chosen" name="Reply[email_to][]" readonly="readonly" multiple="multiple" maxlength="20">
<option value="0">peter@mpesconsulting.com.au</option>
</select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine except the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($mailList as $eachValue){
         $selectedOptions[$eachValue] = array('selected' => 'selected');
    }
```

Assuming `$mailList` is an array like:

```
$mailList = array("a@a.com", "b@b.com", "c@c.com");
```

You have to preselect the value not the content of the `option` tag, so, modify your `foreach` something like:

```
foreach ($mailList as $optionKey=>$optionVal) {
     if ($optionVal) {
        $selectedOptions[$optionKey] = array('selected' => 'selected');
     }
 }
```

This will add the `selected` attribute to the array keys.